# Add bar labels to horizontal histogram in Stata

Tags: histogram, stata

Does anyone know a workaround to adding labels on the bars in a horizontal histogram in Stata? In the help file it says that the horizontal and addlabels command won't work together but I'm hoping there's a nifty way to do it! Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

My data looks like:
con_physical

```
Difficult to FINANCE equipment
Difficult to FINANCE equipment
Difficult to find premises CONNECTED TO SERVICES
Difficult to find premises in an optimal LOCATION
Insufficient supply of WATER
Difficult to FINANCE equipment
Difficult to FINANCE equipment
Difficult to find premises in an optimal LOCATION
Difficult to FINANCE equipment
Low level of AUTOMATION
Difficult to FINANCE equipment
Difficult to FINANCE equipment
Difficult to FINANCE equipment
Difficult to FINANCE equipment
Unreliable supply of ELECTRICITY
Difficult to FINANCE equipment
Unreliable supply of ELECTRICITY
Difficult to FINANCE equipment
Difficult to FINANCE equipment
Difficult to find premises CONNECTED TO SERVICES
Difficult to FINANCE equipment
Difficult to FINANCE equipment
Difficult to find premises CONNECTED TO SERVICES
Difficult to find premises CONNECTED TO SERVICES
Difficult to FINANCE equipment
Unreliable supply of ELECTRICITY
Difficult to find premises in an optimal LOCATION
Difficult to FINANCE equipment
Difficult to find premises CONNECTED TO SERVICES
Low level of AUTOMATION
Difficult to FINANCE equipment
Difficult to find premises that are not in good CONDITION
Difficult to FINANCE equipment
Difficult to FINANCE equipment
Difficult to FINANCE equipment
Difficult to FINANCE equipment
Difficult to FINANCE equipment
Difficult to FINANCE equipment
Difficult to FINANCE equipment
Difficult to FINANCE equipment
Difficult to FINANCE equipment
Difficult to FINANCE equipment
Difficult to FINANCE equipment
Difficult to FINANCE equipment
Difficult to find premises in an optimal LOCATION
Difficult to find premises that are not in good CONDITION
Difficult to find premises that are not in good CONDITION
Difficult to find premises CONNECTED TO SERVICES
Difficult to find premises that are not in good CONDITION
Low level of AUTOMATION
Low level of AUTOMATION
Difficult to find premises CONNECTED TO SERVICES
Unreliable supply of ELECTRICITY
Low level of AUTOMATION
Low level of AUTOMATION
Low level of AUTOMATION
Difficult to find premises in an optimal LOCATION
Low level of AUTOMATION
Difficult to find premises CONNECTED TO SERVICES
Difficult to FINANCE equipment
```

My code is

```
hist con_physical, addlabels title("Biggest Physical Resource Constraint", size(small)) xtitle("Percent of Sample") ytitle("") horizontal discrete percent     bcolor(navy) yla(2/8, valuelabel labsize(vsmall) angle(0))
```

which produces this[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide a reproducible example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for guidance. Why three (and only three) labels appear and what relation they bear to the histogram is unclear without access to your data.

I would not use `histogram` here as first choice. For categories with their own value labels, `graph hbar` is more flexible in most respects.

This example shows some technique with code that will work in your Stata:

```
sysuse auto, clear
graph hbar, over(rep78) blabel(total, format(%2.1f) pos(base)) bar(1, bfcolor(none))
more 
contract rep78
graph hbar (asis) _freq, over(rep78) blabel(total, pos(base)) bar(1, bfcolor(none))
```

In this example, there aren't value labels, but they would be shown if they existed.

Incidentally, the lack of any obvious ordering to your categories makes it a poor graph by many standards. Ordering from most frequent to least is one clear possibility.

Comment: Thanks, Nick! I must admit, I'm fairly new to stackoverflow so I'm not sure of the best way to attach data. I've tried adding in the values from the variable I'm trying to create the histogram for but let me know if that's not what you had in mind!

Comment: For Stata questions you need either example datasets that anyone can read (with `sysuse` or `webuse`, for example) or self-contained datasets that are provided by example. `ssc inst dataex` installs a dedicated command for the latter.

Comment: Your present data could be read in with some effort but I regard the engineering as too much like uninteresting hard work. (I will remove this comment if it becomes untrue.) (Besides, why isn't my answer what you want with translation to your variable names?)